# Do we need to apply the Euclidean Algorithm before applying the Extended Euclidean Algorithm?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, euclidean-algorithm, gcd-and-lcm

As the title says, do we need to apply the Euclidean Algorithm before applying the Extended Euclidean Algorithm?

For example, we have $\gcd(24,17)$, so we can find $x,y$ such that $24x+17y=1$. Applying the Euclidean algorithm:

$$\gcd(24,17)=\gcd(7,17)=\gcd(7,3)=\gcd(1,3)=1$$

Applying the Extended Euclidean algorithm:

\begin{align*} 1 &= 7-2\cdot3 \\ &= 7-2\cdot(17-2\cdot7) \\ &= 5\cdot7-2\cdot17 \\ &=5\cdot(24-17)-2\cdot17 \\ &=5\cdot24-7\cdot17 \end{align*}

Is there a way to do this without first applying the Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: It is spelt "Euclidean". And the answer is no.

Comment: @user21820 Okay, thank you.

Comment: As said by @user21820 the answer is no. The extended algorithm is obtained by enhancing the standard one with computation of the Bezout coefficients as you go. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: I always thought of them as executed simultaneously, not one after the other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name suggests the extended Euclidean algorithm is an extension of the classical algorithm, which means the normal Euclidean algorithm is part of the extended Euclidean algorithm.
normal: Provides gcd
extended provides gcd + the 2 numbers x,y such that gcd= nx + my
whereas n,m are the input numbers

So to answer your original question, yes you don't have to compute the classic Euclidean since you get the gcd at the end.

Look at this simple  [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Example)  from Wikipedia.

I hope this is useful for you.